# One-hot encoding in patsy

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, patsy

For regressions I usually encode categorical variables using sklearn's [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

I am now exploring using patsy but it doesn't appear to offer One-hot encoding: http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html

Is it possible to specify One-hot encoding using patsy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things to know here that might help: (1) patsy by default includes an intercept (there's an invisible `1 +` at the beginning of every formula), and (2) when coding a categorical value, patsy automatically chooses an encoding strategy that avoids creating an over-parameterized model.

If you combine an intercept + full-rank one-hot encoding, then you get an over-parameterized model. So patsy switches to treatment coding (= basically dropping one column from the one-hot encoding you're thinking of). This avoids creating a linear dependence between your encoding columns and the intercept column.

An easy way to avoid this is to remove the intercept -- then patsy won't be worried about the linear dependence, and will use the kind of one-hot encoding you're expecting: `y ~ -1 + a` (the `-1` cancels out the invisible `1` to remove the intercept).

Alternatively, if you really want an over-parameterized model, then if you scroll down further on the docs page you linked to, it tells you how to define arbitrary custom encoding schemes.

```
import numpy as np
from patsy import ContrastMatrix

class FullRankOneHot(object):
    def __init__(self, reference=0):
        self.reference = reference

    # Called to generate a full-rank encoding
    def code_with_intercept(self, levels):
        return ContrastMatrix(np.eye(len(levels)),
                              ["[My.%s]" % (level,) for level in levels])

    # Called to generate a non-full-rank encoding. But we don't care,
    # we do what we want, and return a full-rank encoding anyway.
    # Take that, patsy.
    def code_without_intercept(self, levels):
        return self.code_with_intercept(levels)
```

Then you can use it like: `y ~ 1 + C(a, FullRankOneHot)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example in the link you provided is indeed the one-hot encoding:

```
In [3]: data
Out[3]: {'a': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3']}

In [4]: dmatrix("a", data)
Out[4]: 
DesignMatrix with shape (6, 3)
  Intercept  a[T.a2]  a[T.a3]
          1        0        0
          1        1        0
          1        0        1
          1        0        0
          1        1        0
          1        0        1
  Terms:
    'Intercept' (column 0)
    'a' (columns 1:3)
```

Notice that to encode a categorical variable with 3 levels, you only need 2 binary variables. The encoding in this documentation is treating `a1` as the base and adding two more binary variable for `a2` and `a3`. If both `a2` and `a3` are 0, then it means the value is `a1`.

In sklearn's `OneHotEncoder` or pandas's `pd.get_dummies()`, they return a matrix with same number of columns as the levels of your categorical variables, but that contains one extra column as you can represent the value of one of the columns with the values in other columns.

Comment: I'd like to have the extra column explicitly returned by patsy like it is in sklearn. That way I can directly interpret the coefficients for each level rather than having to interpret them in the context of the intercept. Is that possible? Or are the post-processing tools available in patsy?

Comment: @DontDivideByZero if you have an overparametrized model (like you do when you have an intercept plus one-hot coding for all the values), then you end up with an infinite space of equivalent models with different coefficients, and your fitting code picks one of these arbitrarily. So trying to interpret those coefficients is probably a bad idea anyway; there are infinitely many different coefficients that work just as well.

Comment: this overparameterisation disappears when you use regularisation though